# How to check how many draw results i had and display it?

Tags: java, arrays

Below we have 2  int arrays storing football results for home and away...I need to display statistic  how many draw results i had .Can someones give me a hand with it ?I can not figure it out.Please assume  it is my first ever program and if you have any solution can you comment code please ..I need to explain to my tutor how i did it .thanks

```
    String[] HomeTeam = new String[10];
    String[] AwayTeam = new String[10];
    int[] HomeScore = new int[10];
    int[] AwayScore = new int[10];

    int index = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;

    do 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Home Team Name: ");
        HomeTeam[index] = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Away Team Name: ");
        AwayTeam[index] = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Home Team Score:");
        HomeScore[index] = kbd.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Away Team Score: ");
        AwayScore[index] = kbd.nextInt();
        kbd.nextLine();


    } while(index < 10);
    index = 0;

    System.out.println();   

    do 
    {
        System.out.println(HomeTeam[index] + " [" + HomeScore[index] + "]" + " | " + AwayTeam[index] + " [" + AwayScore[index] + "] ");
        index = index + 1;

    } while(index < 10);

    kbd.close();

    for(index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        sum += HomeScore[index];
        for(index = 0; index < 10; index++)
            sum1 += AwayScore[index];

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Totals");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Total number of matches played: " + index);
    System.out.println("Total of all home scores: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Total of all away scores: " + sum1);
    System.out.println("Total number of draws: ");
    System.out.println("The highest home score: ");
    System.out.println("The highest away score: ");

}
```

}

Comment: create one variable to store draws. loop ten times. get both homescore and awayscore at loop index, if they are equal, sum one to draws count variable.

Comment: "I need to explain to my tutor how i did it" - then you should actually do it, we're glad to give pointers but it is _you_ who is meant to learn what to do and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write your code, you have to be clear about the solution you are implementing. A good beginner practice, is to write a flow chart of your program execution (paper before keyboard).

I made it one for you to take as future reference:

[image]

So, with that algorithm in mind, I implemented a possible solution(with hard coded data).

### MainClass:

```
public class MainE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] homeTeam = { "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p"};
        String[] awayTeam = {"p", "o", "i", "u", "y", "t", "r", "e", "w", "q"};
        int[] homeScore = {5,1,3,5,6,1,10,4,3,2};
        int[] awayScore = {4,3,2,1,3,5,42,1,3,2};

        int sumHome = 0;
        int sumAway = 0;
        int drawCount = 0;

        int highestHomeScore = homeScore[0];
        int highestAwayScore = awayScore[0];

        System.out.println();

        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {

            System.out.println(homeTeam[index] + " [" + homeScore[index] + "]"
                    + " | " + awayTeam[index] + " [" + awayScore[index] + "] ");
            sumHome += homeScore[index];
            sumAway += awayScore[index];

            if (homeScore[index] > highestHomeScore) highestHomeScore = homeScore[index];
            if (awayScore[index] > highestAwayScore) highestAwayScore = awayScore[index];

            if(homeScore[index] == awayScore[index]) drawCount++;
        }



        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Totals");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total number of matches played: " + homeTeam.length);
        System.out.println("Total of all home scores: " + sumHome);
        System.out.println("Total of all away scores: " + sumAway);
        System.out.println("Total number of draws: " + drawCount);
        System.out.println("The highest home score: " + highestHomeScore);
        System.out.println("The highest away score: " + highestAwayScore);

    }

}
```

### output:

```
q [5] | p [4] 
w [1] | o [3] 
e [3] | i [2] 
r [5] | u [1] 
t [6] | y [3] 
y [1] | t [5] 
u [10] | r [42] 
i [4] | e [1] 
o [3] | w [3] 
p [2] | q [2] 

Totals
-------------------------------
Total number of matches played: 10
Total of all home scores: 40
Total of all away scores: 66
Total number of draws: 2
The highest home score: 10
The highest away score: 42
```

---

Edit:

If you want to avoid null values, you have to ask every iteration `if(homeTeam[index] != null )`, also count matches manually (they don't match array length anymore)

### handle null

```
public class MainE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] homeTeam = { "q", "w", "e", null, "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p"};
        String[] awayTeam = {"p", "o", "i", null, "y", "t", "r", "e", "w", "q"};
        int[] homeScore = {5,1,3,0,6,1,10,4,3,2};
        int[] awayScore = {4,3,2,0,3,5,42,1,3,2};

        int sumHome = 0;
        int sumAway = 0;
        int drawCount = 0;
        int matches = 0;

        int highestHomeScore = homeScore[0];
        int highestAwayScore = awayScore[0];

        System.out.println();

        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            if(homeTeam[index] != null ){
                System.out.println(homeTeam[index] + " [" + homeScore[index] + "]"
                        + " | " + awayTeam[index] + " [" + awayScore[index] + "] ");
                sumHome += homeScore[index];
                sumAway += awayScore[index];

                if (homeScore[index] > highestHomeScore) highestHomeScore = homeScore[index];
                if (awayScore[index] > highestAwayScore) highestAwayScore = awayScore[index];

                if(homeScore[index] == awayScore[index]) drawCount++;
                matches++;
            }


        }



        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Totals");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total number of matches played: " + matches);
        System.out.println("Total of all home scores: " + sumHome);
        System.out.println("Total of all away scores: " + sumAway);
        System.out.println("Total number of draws: " + drawCount);
        System.out.println("The highest home score: " + highestHomeScore);
        System.out.println("The highest away score: " + highestAwayScore);

    }

}
```

### output:

```
q [5] | p [4] 
w [1] | o [3] 
e [3] | i [2] 
t [6] | y [3] 
y [1] | t [5] 
u [10] | r [42] 
i [4] | e [1] 
o [3] | w [3] 
p [2] | q [2] 

Totals
-------------------------------
Total number of matches played: 9
Total of all home scores: 35
Total of all away scores: 65
Total number of draws: 2
The highest home score: 10
The highest away score: 42
```

Note: a better option, is to skip null values when asking the input.

Comment: Thanks for  clarification  my code looks almost same  it just telling me that my way of thinking was  correct ...thanks for all ....

Comment: Sure ..can You answer one more question please  when i have
aaa [1] | aaa [1] 
null [0] | null [0]       how to print only inputed elements  without null elements?

Answer (score 0):

Add another local variable called `drawCount`. Loop through the score arrays and check if the elements in both arrays at the loop index are equal. If so then increment `drawCount` by one. Then print at the end.

Also, you can combine your `For` loops into one.

Comment: I didn't post any code so you can try it on your own. If you still need help, please post what you have tried and I can edit my answer.

Comment: int drawCount = 0;
if(HomeScore[index] == AwayScore[index] )
    drawCount++;     but  this one showing  1 in result  nomatter how many draws

Answer (score 0):

You have in your code 2 for loops, but you only need 1 to get all the results you need because all arrays are of size 10.  
So inside this loop:

```
for(index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
   // calculations
}
```

calculate all the sums, the number of draws and the highest scores for Home and Away by using `index` in all the arrays.  
One more suggestion: use more readable names for the variables like:  
`sumMatches`, `sumHomeScore`, `sumAwayScore`, `sumDraws`, `sumHighestHome`, `sumHighestAway`.

Comment: how to do sumDraws   because it must check elements from both arrays?

Comment: You check if the scores from the 2 arrays are equal `if (HomeScore[index] == AwayScore[index]) ...`